# Datatable header is not fixing? suggest me solution for this problem?

Tags: jquery, datatable

Im using  jquery Datatable and the table is scroll datatable .i have try much time to fix datatable header with different ways  but the header is not fixing anyone can help me to fix this isuue.i have add the code of table and datatable and scripts.

this is the html code for table

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-bordered table-striped tblquick " id="Phone_Table">
                                            <thead class="font-weight-light">
                                                <tr>

                                                    <th width="100px"> Numbers</th>
                                                    <th width="100px">Edit</th>
                                                    <th width="100px">Delete</th>

                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody id="Phone_TableBody">

                                                @foreach (var item in Model.NumberList)
                                                {

                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td width="100px" style="font:small">@item.PHONE_NUMBER</td>
                                                        <td width="100px">
                                                            <a class="Update" href="#">Update</a>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td width="100px"><a href="#">Delete</a></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                }

                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
```

this is the scripts which im using to fix the datatable header and for datatable

```
  @section scripts{
            <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.datatables.js"></script>
            <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/datatables.bootstrap.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css">
            <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
            <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

this is the datatable code for

```
          var table = $('#Phone_Table').DataTable({
                    "bAutoWidth": false,

                    "bScrollCollapse": true,
                    "responsive": true,

                    "fixedHeader": true,

                    "searching": true,


                    "bDestroy": true,
                    "dom": "<'row'<'col-lg-12'tr>>" +
                    "<'row'<'col-lg-3'l><'col-lg-12'p>>",
                    "oLanguage": {
                        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ ",
                        "fixedHeader": true,
                        "fixedHeader": {
                            header: true,

                        }


                    },

                });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your js and css import are messed up

You are importing js file in css link

eg:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js">
```

Here is the [Datatable doc for fixed header](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/header_footer.html)

also [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xF8hZ/3/)

To start with just replace your css and js in script section with this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.5/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```